# Use two different index pages

Tags: redirect, htaccess

This [link](http://www.imlovingdogs.com) is pointing to my home directory. I want my users to see `~/home/prototype.php` page when they come to my site.
To achieve this, I have set following in my .htaccess file of that directory:

```
DirectoryIndex /home/prototype.php
# BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress
```

There is a form which they need to fill and submit. The redirection of this form is set to `www.imlovingdogs.com/index.php` i.e. the main index.php page where wordpress starts loading other required files. But this `www.imlovingdogs.com/index.php` doesn't work! How can I achieve this kind of flow for  my users?

Answer (score 2):

You can't set `DirectoryIndex` to `prototype.php` and expect everything else to work correctly. `DirectoryIndex` is not just a "landing page". A lot of requests go through that file.

I think you are making this more complicated than it needs to be.

1. Put your code for `prototype.php` into a WordPress [custom theme
   template file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates).
2. [Create a page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Pages) that uses that file as the template
3. Set that page as the [static front page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page).

That lets you keep everything inside WordPress so you can do things like track whether a user is logged in and whether that user has filled out the form, and redirect away from the page if so. And you don't need to mess with rewriting at all.

There is another similar but mostly opposite approach.

Don't try to rewrite anything and let WordPress operate as normal.
But use the `template_redirect` hook to check for user logged in status and to check if the user has filled in the form, and conditionally redirect to your form.

```
function redirect_to_prototypephp_wpse_101519() {
  $redir = true;
  if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $filled_form = get_user_meta($user_id, '_prototype_form', true);
    if (true == $filled_form) {
      $redir = false;
    }
  }
  if (true === $redir) {
    wp_redirect('http://your-url/URL/to/prototype.php');
  }
}
add_action('template_redirect','redirect_to_prototypephp_wpse_101519');
```

This also allows you to use core WordPress functions but in a different way. The only additional component would be the need to set the `_prototype_form` usermeta key when the `prototype.php` form is submitted.

Comment: I am following your steps. I have set the front page as different page that has all my code from prototype.php. that works fine now. But now the issue is, when the default option was selected: "your latest posts", the page was different. However, I can't find the same page in the posts page dropdownlist under the settings. how can I find that?

Comment: I am not sure I understand you, but (I think) you need to create a page to serve as your post index page, then select that page from the dropdown at `wp-admin->Settings->Reading`

Comment: ok let me try again. Before modifying anything, in the reading section, the front page display was set to "your latest posts". The page lets call it as "A", that I was able to see was different with topbar nav, slideshow, etc. Now, after changing the option to a static page, the front page is now changed. however, I am not able to find how to get the same page "A" in the posts page dropdownlist or just get the url of that page.

Comment: in other words: What file is the standard frontpage that lists all the posts?

Comment: Does your theme have a `home.php` or a `front-page.php`?

Comment: yes it has home.php

Comment: That is probably the customized code for your blog index. Use it to create a custom template like you did for the prototype page.

Comment: I have already tried that but it doesn't work. `home.php` contains following code; `<?php get_header(); ?>
  
<?php get_template_part('includes/default'); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9047/discussion-between-s-ha-dum-and-yoda)